# sql query to select records from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am developing an application using Oracle as back end.I have created two tables for recording expense details `"exp_mater"` & `"exp_details"`.

```
exp_master(parti_id(pk),particulars);

exp_details(exp_id(pk),parti_id(fk),amount);

table exp_master
parti_id|particulars
--------|-----------
  1     | incentive
  2     | papers
  3     | salary


table exp_details
  exp_id|parti_id|amount
------  |--------|
 e1     | 2      |200
 e2     | 1      |100
 e3     | 2      |1000
```

Now I want to select desired records from both the tables but the out put should be like:

```
    parti_id  | particulars | amount
--------------|-------------|-------
     2        |papers       |100
     1        |incentive    |200
     2        |papers       |100
```

I have tried sub queries but I was able to show only the particulars field and not other two .Is there any way to do this.

thanks in advance

Comment: show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Why do you list `papers` twice? And why are there two rows with an amount of `100` for `papers` in the output, but the data contains one row with `100` and one row with `1000`?

Answer (score 0):

You could join both tables and then sum the amount:

```
SELECT    m.parti_id, particulars, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM      exp_mater m
LEFT JOIN exp_details d ON m.parti_id = d.parti_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    m.parti_id, particulars, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM      exp_mater m
Inner JOIN exp_details d ON m.parti_id = d.parti_id
```

an inner join is needed here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

depends on your requirement,

```
SELECT    m.parti_id, particulars, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM      exp_mater m
Inner JOIN exp_details d ON m.parti_id = d.parti_id 
Group By m.parti_id, particulars
```

or

```
SELECT    m.parti_id, particulars, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM      exp_mater m
LEFT OUTER JOIN exp_details d ON m.parti_id = d.parti_id 
Group By m.parti_id, particulars
```